# Trying to auto-run UnitTests within Unity

Tags: c#, unit-testing, unity-game-engine, nunit

I'm trying to do something like this

```
class CustomPreProcessBuild : IPreprocessBuild
{
    public void OnPreprocessBuild(BuildTarget _target, string _builtPath)
    {
        Debug.Log("CustomPreProcessBuild-OnPreprocessBuild for target " + _target + " at path: " + _builtPath);

        // TODO: run tests
        Debug.Log("Reminder! Run unit tests before building the project");
    }
}
```

As my code sample describes, I want to auto-run all of my unit tests before execution of a `Build` command.
Is there a way to auto-run all UnitTests from the C# code within Unity?

I'm using 2017.3

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Unity Test Runner. Here's the documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/testing-editortestsrunner.html

If you don't use this test runner, you won't be able to test MonoBehavior derivatives(your custom components).

Comment: I'm using this, but I want to auto-run it from C# script

Comment: You can't, because you can't instantiate a Monobehaviour outside of Unity. If you only wanna test a C# class that is not derived from Monobehaviour, you can then run the test with something like NUnit test runner

Comment: yes, i want to test UnitTests which don't use MonoBehaviour. can you describe how to do it according to my given sample code

Comment: I've never done that, but apparently this IDE has some support for it: https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware you cannot invoke tests from a script, as yet. Although I'm not overly familiar with the version you're running. However, I did see a post a while back on reflection of the Batch class, with the aim of invoking. Can't seem to find it for the life of me now though.

You can run them from the command line, so I guess you could try running it via a process from `System.Diagnostics`namespace. Not sure how well Unity will take two of itself running, as the test runner uses the Unity exe, still, it's worth a shot!

Comment: the given batch solution (on unity documentation) works on windows, while my team members are on windows and mac, too. so i want to auto-run all tests from C# scripts before making the build

Comment: also that batch solution is not auto-run, which can be called in a c# script

Comment: Then, the only other option that I know of, would be to see if you can run them from the command line, via a process. It may/may not work, but as I say, it's worth a look as it may solve the issue for you. Good luck!

Comment: in that case, it would not be an auto-run

Answer (score 0):

This was a script I created that more or less does what you are looking for. It can be called through the editor (via the Tests MenuItem) or called through the command line. I only created the script to run Edit Mode unit tests here because of the Assembly Definition requirement you need to set up throughout your project to additionally run Play Mode tests. If you want to run both, you simply need to run both of them through the TestRunnerApi and stitch the results together.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.TestTools.TestRunner.Api;

namespace UnitTesting
{
    public static class UnitTestingProcessor
    {
        /************************************************************/
        #region Properties

        static TestRunnerApi _api;
        static TestRunnerApi Api
        {
            get
            {
                if (_api == null) _api = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<TestRunnerApi>();
                return _api;
            }
        }

        static TestCallbacks _callbacks;
        static TestCallbacks Callbacks
        {
            get
            {
                if (_callbacks == null) _callbacks = new TestCallbacks();
                return _callbacks;
            }
        }

        #endregion
        /************************************************************/
        #region Functions

        #region Processor Functions

        [MenuItem("Tests/Run Edit Mode Unit Tests", false, 10)]
        public static void StartUnitTestingProcessor()
        {
            RunEditModeTests();
        }

        private static void Exit(int exitCode)
        {
            if (Application.isBatchMode) EditorApplication.Exit(exitCode);
        }

        #endregion
        
        #region Test Functions

        private static void RunEditModeTests()
        {   
            Api.RegisterCallbacks(Callbacks);

            Filter filter = new Filter();
            filter.testMode = TestMode.EditMode;
            ExecutionSettings executionSettings = new ExecutionSettings(filter);

            Api.Execute(executionSettings);
        }

        private static void FinishEditModeTests(ITestResultAdaptor result)
        {   
            Api.UnregisterCallbacks(Callbacks);

            if (result.ResultState == "Passed") 
            {
                Debug.Log("Edit Mode Unit Tests Succeeded");
                Exit(0);
            }
            else
            {   
                Debug.LogError("Edit Mode Unit Tests Failed");
                Exit(1);
            }
        }

        #endregion
        
        #endregion
        /************************************************************/
        #region Subclasses

        private class TestCallbacks : ICallbacks
        {
            public void RunStarted(ITestAdaptor testsToRun) 
            {
                Debug.Log($"EditMode Run Started");
            }

            public void RunFinished(ITestResultAdaptor result) 
            {
                Debug.Log($"EditMode Run Finished");
                FinishEditModeTests(result);
            }

            public void TestStarted(ITestAdaptor test) 
            {
                // Debug.Log($"Test {test.Name} Started");
            }

            public void TestFinished(ITestResultAdaptor result)
            {
                if (result.HasChildren) return; 
                
                if (result.ResultState == "Passed") return;
                
                Debug.LogError($"{result.ResultState}: {result.Test.Name}");
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```